# looping the jquery function when we have multiple list

Tags: jquery, html, loops

The script below should add 'selected' class to the item in the unordered list, indicated by the number in the span abouve it.

It is working when I have a single division with one span and list, but not when I repeat it multiple times.

Can anyone ewplain why and advice me how to repear it?

```
var selected = parseInt($(".number").html(), 10) - 1;
$('.number').parent(".quantity-select").find("li:eq("+selected+")").addClass("selected");

<div class="quantity-select">
<span class="number">1</span>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="quantity-select">
<span class="number">3</span>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tell us what the script should do, instead of letting each of us find out. (You are not sending a mail, you are adding a toppic to a knowledge base that will be consulted for years to come.)

Comment: Hi Dirk, if number 3 is written then add 'selected' class to 3rd list, if number 1 is written then add class to first list. it should be in loop so that if we have multiple "quantity-select" blocks then script has to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selected` variable only picks up the first value, so when you apply it to the multiple lists, you will use the same, single value.

You would need a loop, and get the `selected` value in each iteration of it. 
I would suggest looping over the wrapping `div` elements as follows:

```js
$(".quantity-select").each(function () {
    var selected = $(".number", this).text() - 1;
    $("li:eq("+selected+")", this).addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity-select">
    <span class="number">1</span>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="quantity-select">
    <span class="number">3</span>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```